# How to store a value calculated and use it in code?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to calculate the difference between two points, get the percentage and use this float value as the default value for the `input.float` on the next line.

I am getting the difference of the 2 values like this:

`Calculation2_01 = math.round((entryPrice2_01 / midasPrice2_01) * 100, 2) - 100`

But if I try to use this value as a default in `Line1_01` it says *Undeclared identifier 'Line1_01'*

`Line1_01 = input.float(Calculation2_01)`

And if I write `Line1_01 = Calculation2_01` it does not start plotting from the point I want it to plot.

How can I store the result of `Calculation2_01` and use it as the default value?

[picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VuJd.png)

This is the Full Working Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Anchored VWAP", overlay=true)
src = input.source(hl2, "Source")
startCalculationDate = input.time(timestamp("20 Jan 2021"), "Start Calculation", confirm=true)
endBar01 = input.time(timestamp("20 Feb 2021"), "Get Midas Percentage", confirm=true)

vwap_calc() =>
    var srcVolArray = array.new_float(na)
    var volArray = array.new_float(na)
    if startCalculationDate <= time
        array.push(srcVolArray, src*volume)
        array.push(volArray, volume)
    else
        array.clear(srcVolArray), array.clear(volArray)
    array.sum(srcVolArray)/array.sum(volArray)
anchoredVwap = vwap_calc()
plot(anchoredVwap, "VWAP", linewidth=3)

getPriceForTime(t)=>
    var float price = na
    if time[1] <= t and time >= t and na(price)
        price := high
    price

getMidasForTime(t)=>
    var float price = na
    if time[1] <= t and time >= t and na(price)
        price := anchoredVwap
    price

float midasPrice2_01    = getMidasForTime(endBar01)   
float entryPrice2_01    = getPriceForTime(endBar01) 

 // This is the calculation for the Percentage
Calculation2_01   = math.round((entryPrice2_01 / midasPrice2_01) * 100, 2) - 100

Line1_01    = Calculation2_01
Band1_01    = anchoredVwap * ((100 + Line1_01) / 100)

trend = str.tostring(Calculation2_01)
f_print(_txt) =>
    var _lbl = label.new(endBar01, high, _txt, xloc.bar_time, yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_label_down, color = color.navy, textcolor = color.white, size = size.small)
    label.set_xy(_lbl, endBar01, high)
    label.set_text(_lbl, _txt + "%")
f_print(trend)

// I want to plot this band where anchoredVwap Starts.
plot(Band1_01, "VWAP", color.white, linewidth=1)
```

Comment: `input.x()` functions are for user inputs. You cannot call a function or sth else in those. Please share your code so we can offer some workarounds.

Comment: @vitruvius I've added the full code. `Line1_01 = Calculation2_01` works, but it does not work as I want (like I showed in the picture attached). I need a workaround to use the result of `Calculation2_01`

Comment: @vitruvius did you get to have a look?